# adb.exe is not executable. ANDROID_HOME is not set

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am successful in taking snapshot and open a activity using monkeyrunner. But what I want is to press a Button. So I am using ViewClient, but whenever I run my jython script the error comes:

```
File "F:\Example\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 870, in _init_()
File "F:\Example\AndroidViewClient\src\com\dtmilano\android\viewclient.py", line 986 in _ViewClient_obtainAdbPath
```

raises exception

```
('adb="%s" is not executable. Did you forget to set ANDROID_HOME in the environment?' %adb)
Exception: adb="%s" is not executable. Did you forget to set ANDROID_HOME in the environment?
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What OS are you using? Well, depending on your OS, you need to tell it where your Android SDK is located. For example, in Ubuntu machine, I have the following line in my .bashrc:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/roberto/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/roberto/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export ANDROID_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME
export PATH
```

If you are on a Windows machine, then you need to add this path to your Windows Environment's PATH.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say here. Thumbs up!!

Comment: I have path variable set in Windows Environment Variable.It points to my sdk's Tools and Platform-tools. Recently I changed my sdk-16 to sdk-17.

Comment: Be careful, because ANDROID_HOME is expected to have a single directory value only. There's only one HOME.

Comment: Do I need to set ANDROID_HOME variable explicitely?

Comment: Probably not. You should be able to append the two paths to the PATH variable

Comment: Yes, set ANDROID_HOME explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
set ANDROID_HOME=c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
```

Or any other place where you put Android SDK in your installation.

Replace 'Administrator' with your local Windows username (based on locale).

Tested on MS Windows 7 x64 Ultimate with Russian locale 
and JAVA/JRuby versions:

```
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

and

```
jruby 9.0.0.0 (2.2.2) 2015-07-21 e10ec96 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.51
-b03 on 1.8.0_51-b16 +jit [Windows 7-amd64]
io/console not supported; tty will not be manipulated
NameError: undefined local variable or method `rsion' for main:Object
<top> at -e:1
```